# Data always empty AJAX call Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to RAILS and even more to AJAX calls.

I have a search bar where I want to perform an autocomplete to help users find items present in the db.
For the moment I am only trying to display the data of the AJAX call inside the console but whatever I do it is always empty...

I am using Rails 5.2.1

My form :

```html
<%= form_tag autocomplete_index_path,remote: true,  method: :get do %>
 <%= text_field_tag 'term', params[:term], class:"my_form"%>
  <%= submit_tag "bouton", class: "my_button" %>
<% end %>
```

My controller (using pg search):

```html
class AutocompleteController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render json: { data: Beer.search_beer(params[:term]).limit(5)}  } 
    end
  end
end
```

And my assets/javascripts file

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".my_form").keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();

        if(search != ""){

            $.ajax({
                url: 'autocomplete',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {'name': $("#term").val()},
                success:function(data){
                 console.log('Success!', data);
                }
                });
        }

    });

});
```

Beer model with pg scope

```html
class Beer < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch
  belongs_to :brewery
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :style
  has_many :bars, through: :beer_lists
  pg_search_scope :search_beer, 
    against: :name, 
    using: {
      tsearch: {
        prefix: true
      }
    }
end
```

If someone could help me figure out why Ajax call is always rendering an empty array it would much appreciated !

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC43u.png)

[Rails server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D5OT.png)

Comment: Is your ajax request is successfully going to your controller  ? Can you please check this first and please add terminal log of your ajax call

Comment: Yes it is successfully connected as I can see that the search is performed in the rails console, but with en empty text parameter. I added the browser and rails console log

Comment: Try to add terminal logs (rails server) not browser logs .

Comment: This is because your `params[:term]` is empty so there is no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Have you checked the `params[:term]` actually contains the string you enter ? For example by adding a `binding.pry` at the beginning of your index method in your controller, and checking in terminal console what's the value of `params[:term]` when the code is stopped by `binding.pry`?

2) What is your `search_beer` method?
Have you tried definining a pg search scope in your Beer model, as explained here:https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#user-content-pg_search_scope ?
Then you could have a `search_by_name` method (if your Beer model has a `name` attribute) so that `Beer.search_by_name(params[:term])`returns an array of beers whose name match what you have in `params[:term]`

Comment: I have added the Beer model to let you see the search_beer method. Let me check the value of param[:terms] with binding.pry

Comment: as you said params[:term] is nil but I really don't see why its not filled with the text entered in the form ...

Comment: In the console when you are stopped at the binding.pry point you can request for the value of `params`, what does it contain?

Comment: When I puts params  I have this 

{"name"=>"fg", "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"autocomplete", "action"=>"index"}, no trace of the text field

Comment: Ok so that means that there may be an issue with the html... If you inspect in your browser the html for your form, do you have a `<input type="text" name="term" />` ?

Comment: Yes I have exactly that :
 <input type="text" name="term" id="term" class="my_form">

Comment: This is really weird I tried with your exact same code on my side (except the JS at this point, just to check the params) and I do have  `params[:term]` that matches the characters entered in the form. Where exactly did you add the `binding.pry`? PS : actually I think that in your text_field_tag you don't need to specify `params[:term]`, I get the same replacing it by `nil` following this syntax to add a class to a text_field_tag https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag

Comment: I have put it right at the beginning  of the Index function. I think I start seeing what's happening here : params[:term] are only filled when I click the button but not while I type inside the texfield

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If my answer helped you, could you please upvote it? Thanks and have a nice day, happy to help further if needed

Comment: I found what was wrong thanks to you thank you so much !!